# mysql query order ASC starting from 1 then show all with zero

Tags: mysql

I have a column 'order' where I store articles and then show them in a specific order. I use enum type '0','1','2','3' with 0 as default. I need a query to order the result as this: 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0 and so on with zeros.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
select * from table
order by val = '0', val
```

This will work even you add new values values to the enum later.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select ...
from ...
order by case `order` when 0 then 4 else `order` end asc
```

Comment: Hmm. Did you `order by desc`? You should `order by asc`